# SDTT shows only the first 'Hotel' in @graph

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I have created some `Hotel` schema, but want to include 3 as a list. The individual hotel schema works but using `@graph` and trying to include a list doesn't.

I cannot see what's wrong. The testing tool only shows the first `Hotel` and not the second.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{  
   "@context":"http://schema.org",
   "@graph":[  
  {  
     "@type":"Hotel",
     "name" : "The Hampshire Hotel",
 "description" : "A boutique hotel with 42 rooms, excellent value for money located just outside of St Helier.",
 "address" : { "@type" : "PostalAddress",
       "addressCountry" : "Jersey",
           "addressLocality" : "St Helier",
           "postalCode" : "JE2 4TB",
           "streetAddress" : "53 Val Plaisant"
         },
 "photo" : "TBC our image link",
 "telephone" :  "+441534 724 115",
 "PetsAllowed" : "No",
 "priceRange" : "£49 - £100",
 "starRating" :  "3*",
"amenityFeature" : [
"Swimming Pool",
"Bar & restaurant",
"Car parking",
"24hour service",
"Free Wifi"
]
  }
   ]
},      
  {  
   "@type":"Hotel",
     "name" : "The Club Hotel & Spa",
"description" : "A luxury boutique hotel in the heart of St Helier, offering outstanding restaurant, spa and swimming pools.",
"address" : { "@type" : "PostalAddress",
       "addressCountry" : "Jersey",
           "addressLocality" : "St Helier",
           "postalCode" : "JE2 4UH",
           "streetAddress" : "Green Street"
         },
  "photo" : "TBC our image link",
  "telephone" :  "+44 1534 876500",
  "starRating" :  "5*",
  "PetsAllowed" : "No",
"priceRange" : "£83 - £224",
 "amenityFeature" : [
"Swimming Pools",
"Spa",
"Bar & restaurant",
"24hour service",
"Free Wifi"
         ]
   }
   ]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You open two brackets without closing them, and they aren’t needed in the first place, so you have to remove them:

```json
}
 ]
```

These are between the two `Hotel` nodes: between the `]` (from `amenityFeature`) and the `},` (that closes the first `Hotel` node).

Comment: Oh I see, I cannot tell where?

Comment: @Becky: Between the two `Hotel` nodes: between the `]` (from `amenityFeature`) and the `},` (that closes the first `Hotel` node).

Comment: @Becky: You’re welcome. You can accept this answer to mark the question as solved. (I noticed that some of [your other questions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/97252/becky?tab=questions) are also answered, so if the answers solved your question, please accept these, too.)

Comment: Hi @unor - sorry I didn't realise I needed to do this thanks